# 端末上の音声ファイルをユーザーに選択させ、monaca上で再生するには

Tags: monaca

monaca でAndroid向けアプリを作成しております。
その機能の中で、ローカルに保存している音声ファイルを登録し、後に再生ボタンで再生する機能が必要です。

現在、AUDIO要素にて再生などのコントロールは実装されており、実際に再生できる状態です。
AUDIO@SRCを指定すれば問題ないトコロですが、
ユーザーに端末に持っている音声ファイルを選択させる方法が分かりません。

- input@type="file" で指定したファイルのパスを参照してもダミーパスしか取れない
- AUDIO で再生可能なファイルのみ選択させたい